# Installing RAMs with different brand, CL and other differences

Tags: laptop, memory

I have a Samsung 4gb 2666Mhz ddr4 SODIMM memory installed (but working on 2400Mhz due to motherboard limitation). More info about this RAM here https://semiconductor.samsung.com/emea/dram/module/sodimm/m471a5244cb0-ctd/

and here

https://download.semiconductor.samsung.com/resources/data-sheet/M471A5244CB0-CTD00.pdf

The CL of the installed memory is 19.

I want to add another 4gb one but it is from a different brand (Crucial).
I found these 2 in the market but I couldn't decide (since they also have a different organization(rank x organization): **1Rx8**):

**Crucial 4GB DDR4-2400 SODIMM CT4G4SFS824A**

> Technology         DDR4, Density           4GB, Module type        SODIMM, DIMM type           Unbuffered, Voltage         1.2V, Speed             DDR4-2400, CAS latency      17, Extended timings    17-17-17, PC4-19200

**Crucial 4GB DDR4-2666 SODIMM CT4G4SFS8266**

> Technology         DDR4, Density           4GB, Module type        SODIMM, DIMM type           Unbuffered, Voltage         1.2V, Speed             DDR4-2666, CAS latency      19, Extended timings    19-19-19, PC4-21300

I wanna know if it is possible to mix RAMs of different brands. If it is possible, what points do I need to consider to choose the one to buy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if your BIOS even lets you change the memory settings at all, many don't.  If your motherboard BIOS allows you to tweak enough settings it is likely but NOT guaranteed you will find compatible settings.

Yes, but with limitation.
You will have to use the worst timings for ALL memory chips.
So even though some memory supports 17-17-17 the worst times are 19-19-19 and you will have to use those for ALL memory.

Across every category you will need to use the worst numbers, which in memory timing that usually means the largest number.

Comment: >First check if your BIOS even lets you change the memory settings at all, many don't.

By **settings**, do you mean running on single/dual channel or something else?

Comment: The memory timings CAS, CL, RAS, and etc.